# Is there Any Methods Like TernaryOperator to simplify muliple if statements to reduce Cognitive complexity?

Tags: c#, if-statement, asp.net-core-6.0

This is my code in .net core6. in this i want to remove the cognitive complexity . I have used Ternary operator to solve the problem in some codes.But here i cant use that because its a function calling. How can i fix it..?

```
private static Action<CorsPolicyBuilder> CorsPolicyBuilder(Cors config)
    {
        return builder =>
        {
            if (!config.AllowedOrigins.Equals("*"))
            {
                if (config.AllowCredentials)
                {
                    builder.AllowCredentials();
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.DisallowCredentials();
                }
            }
            builder.WithOrigins(config.AllowedOrigins)
                .WithMethods(config.AllowedMethods)
                .WithHeaders(config.AllowedHeaders)
                .WithExposedHeaders(config.ExposedHeaders)
                .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(config.MaxAge));
        };
    }
```

Comment: What is cognitively complex about that? It's more complex to use a ternary: `(!config.AllowedOrigins.Equals("*") ? (Action)builder.AllowCredentials : builder.DisallowCredentials)();` but it's certainly allowed to use a ternary to choose a function to call..

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own extensions method `WithCredentials(bool)`, which calls `AllowCredentials()` or `DisallowCredentials()` depending on provided value, and use it like:

```
builder.WithCredentials(!config.AllowedOrigins.Equals("*"))
```

Comment: to be fair, the new method should also receive as an parameter the value of `config.AllowCredentials`

Comment: Just pass the `config` instance: `builder.WithCredentials(config)`